# my flutter app do not run in iphone device from android studio

Tags: flutter, dart

> When I run for the application from the xcode it works, and same thing
> in simulator , but when I do the run from the Android Studio in iphone
> device, It displays a white screen and then shuts down, and it appears
> like this :

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 7R6D66J964
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build failed due to concurrent builds, will retry in 2 seconds.
Xcode build done.                                           44.9s
Installing and launching...
Error launching application on iPhone.
```

[image]

> flutter doctor :

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.24.0-2.0.pre.55, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64, locale en-JO)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    ! Error: iPhone is busy: Copying cache files from device. Xcode will continue when iPhone is finished. (code -10)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Please provide the error output text instead of a photo. Can you also run `flutter run --verbose` in the main directory and share the output?

Comment: i am editing for error output .

the output for ` flutter run --verbose ` is very long , copy past here ?

Comment: Android studio doesn't provide error for ios. Try running on Xcode, you will your error there

Comment: now show the error , this is error " Could not build module 'nanopb' "

Comment: Please copy and paste the error from `flutter run --verbose` command.  Also clean the project with `flutter clean` and check if there is any issue with `flutter doctor` and last check the project has any errors with `flutter analyze`.

Comment: sorry i am beginer in flutter , just this error :[  +23 ms] Error: iPhone is busy: Copying cache files from device. Xcode will continue when iPhone is finished. (code -10)

Comment: can you help me  ?

Answer (score -1):

Open Xcode
go to Wondow -> Devices & simulator
your phone showing left side
right click on that and unpair
no pair the device and it's working properly